# C++ How to make transparent watermark using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to make my watermark transparent with low opacity, but it seems just setting the colors to white:

[image]

This is the code I'm using which BTW I found in some [website](https://answers.opencv.org/question/73114/how-to-change-transparency-of-an-4-channels-image/?sort=latest)

```
/////////////////// Blending Images (Making Alpha) ////////////////////////

int main()
{
    Mat img, img_bgra;
    string img_path = "res/test.png";

    img = imread(img_path);
    if (img.data == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Image is not loaded!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cvtColor(img, img_bgra, ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
    vector<Mat> channels(4);
    split(img_bgra, channels);

    channels[3] = channels[3] * 0.1;

    merge(channels.data(), 4, img_bgra);

    imwrite("res/transparent.png", img_bgra);
    imshow("Image", img_bgra);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I want the watermark to be displayed like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

i`m no good with C++, so i will try to explain with python example, hopefully this will be readable enough to help

```
alpha = 0.1  # maximum watermark opacity
imageSource = cv2.imread("res/test.png")  # assuming BGR, uint8
imageWatermark = cv2.imread("res/transparent.png")  # assuming BGRA, uint8

maskWatermark = imageWatermark[:,:, 3]  # copy the alpha(transparency) channel, uint8
maskWatermark = np.float32(maskWatermark)*(1/255)*alpha  # convert to float, normalize, apply transparency mul
maskSource = 1 -maskWatermark  # float32, mask out the things we want to keep

imageWatermark = cv2.cvtColor(imageWatermark, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)  # convert to same colorspace as source (3 channels), uint8

imageResult = np.uint8( np.float32(imageSource)*maskSource 
                       +np.float32(imageWatermark)*maskWatermark))  # blend, convert to uint8
cv2.imshow('result', imageResult)
```

Key points here are:

- some sort of mask is needed to tell which pixels of watermark are
  going to affect the resulting image
- blending is like interpolation between two color vectors, where
  opacity acts like t-coordinate; this is done for each correspoinding
  pixel pairs of two images
- carefully watch data types to avoid overflow
- images must be of same dimensions; if they`re not, you should shrink
  or extend them in some way. I think that watermark is most likely is
  much smaller than the image is. In this case you may want to copy the
  watermarke part of the image (which matches watermark dimensions),
  apply watermark and then copy back the watermarked fragment

Comment: Thank you, but I'm no good in Python, I can't translate your code into C++.